# Spring Security: how to retrieve username to accessDeniedPage?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Security, HTML and thymeleaf and I would to retrieve the user that has failed the login. The login has two step: the first step checks if user and password are correct into LDAP, the second checks if user has a role into database. Only if both are passed the user is authenticated. Now I would like to have into my registration page the user that has failed the login (a precompiled input field). The registration page is the accessDeniedPage. This is the authentication:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
            String name = authentication.getName();
            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || password == null || password.isEmpty())
                return null;
            boolean isFind = ldapServices.ldapSearch(name, password);                           
            if (isFind){
                com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(name);
                if (user!=null){
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRole().getRole()));  
                }
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
            }           
            else return null;
        }
```

and the redirect is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    List<Role> roles=roleServices.getRoles();
    //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
    String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (Role role:roles){
        rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
    }

    http
    .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
    //the "/register" path are accepted without login
    .antMatchers("/registration/**").authenticated()
    //all the path need authentication
    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)//.authenticated()
    .and()//Login Form configuration for all others
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    //redirect on page "registration" if user doens't exist in DART database
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/registration")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .permitAll();
}
```

If I add Principal in my /registration controller it is null. Why?
Principal is null, maybe something is wrong in the authenticate method. Furthermore I may have a problem with security since my registration web services are not authenticated whereas they Should be authenticated without any role
Is there a possibility to have into registration page the user that fails the login?
Thanks

Comment: In my opinion your last question answer is yes. By default if any user logged and if this user has no access any page you can get information of user from Principal.

Comment: Principal return null, I have also tried with @AuthenticationPrincipal User user and with sec:authentication="principal.username" in HTML code, all of them are null

Comment: I understood from your security conf if any registered user want to open registration page you want to display you don't have access to this page. Is it true?

Comment: If a user is into LDAP but not into database (he will not have a role) then he is redirected to register page and I would like to fill into registration form his name (because otherwise I should require user and password). Web services used for form are not authenticated because otherwise I receive forbidden error

Comment: I used following:     `@RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accessIsDenied(Principal user) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", user.getName());
        modelAndView.setViewName("403");
        return modelAndView;
    }` And I can get userName.

Comment: Maybe I have find the problem, user is null because it doesn't find it into database so the query return null, instead I should create a user with only username. Now I'm trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed this row into authenticate method:

```
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user==null?new User(name,null,false):user, password, authorities);
```

User was null because he didn't exist into database so the query return null object, instead I have to create a user with only username.